# How to update a standard field status when the email (from send email functionality) has been sent

Tags: apex, trigger

How can I automatically update the quote status picklist field to a specific value ("Presented"):

- When Email is sent with the send email fonctionnality List item,
- Using a specific template (where Subject.startsWith?).

Approach:

Perform a picklist value change if a Task object is created where the WhatId field is a Quote object?

And where the email subject starts with "Specific text"?

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to update the field with **process builder**!

A workflow based on ***"email object"*** doesn't allow to update any other object than ***"cases"*** but **process builder** does.

In fact, **Process builder** allows to pick any object related to the email.

[image: Process builder on email to update field]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a trigger for that on the `EmailMessage` object, but I think you can solve this **without coding** creating a Workflow Rule on that same object, and adjusting the criteria to trigger the rule as being the subject or template used on the email.

If the rule needs to trigger when a specific record is referenced (like a quote) I believe you can get the first three characters in the rule criteria and check if it the object you want (example: `BEGINS(WhatId, '0Q0')`).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I created a worflow rule on the email object with the criteria to trigger when specific object and when referenced to a quote but the workflow only allows to update a "Case" object... not quotes.

Comment: Well, if you can't use workflow rules then I think you will have to use a trigger then.